# How should I run Emacs ERT tests when I need GUI tests?

Tags: emacs, ert

I ran tests with `ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit`. And it's ok for terminal.
But now I need Emacs with GUI to be tested.

And technically `ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit` even works.
But the result in a shell will be like:

```
make test
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

And that's it. All ERT `(backtrace)` will be killed with Emacs (in it's `*Messages*` buffer).

I just want to find a way to print it to the stdout so that I could see what was wrong.

UPD: Maybe some tricks with `standard-output` variable?